# Question about number of elements in $HK$ if $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups of some group $G$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be the finite subgroups of some universal group $G$. Define
$$HK = \{hk \,| \, h \in H, k \in K \}$$
I want to prove that $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$, where $|Q|$ is the number of elements in set $Q$.
This was my process:

1. I proved that $H\cap K$ is also a subgroup.
2. Think of $HK$ as a collection of left cosets of $K$ defined by $H$ i.e.
   $$HK = h_1 K \cup h_2 K \cup \ldots \cup h_{|H|} K $$
3. The set $HK$ as defined above has $|H||K|$ products. But if an element of $hk$ is repeated, we need to make sure we don't overcount.
4. If $$hk = h'k' \\
   hk = (ht)(t^{-1}k) \implies h' = ht, k' = t^{-1} k\\ $$
   where $t \in H \cap K$.
   This tells me that each element of $HK$ has at least $|H\cap K|$ repetitions, each.

The problem I have is, how do I prove that if $t \in H$ but $t \notin K$, the statement $h' = ht, k' = t^{-1}k$ is untrue?

Essentially, if $a \in G, b\notin G$, is it always true that $ab \notin G$?

The closure property of groups states that if $a,b \in G$, then $ab\in G$. But it makes no mention of $a \in G$ and $b \notin G$. I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I can't place my finger on it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A canonical construction proving $\left|HK\right| = \left|H\right|\left|K\right| / \left|H \cap K\right|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813529/a-canonical-construction-proving-lefthk-right-lefth-right-leftk-right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(The "essentially" part in the question)

Let $G\le P, a\in G, b\in P-G.$ Suppose $ab\in G$, then $a^{-1}(ab)=b\in G$, a contradiction. So $ab\notin G$. Note that we need to assume that there is some group containing both $a$ and $b$, otherwise $ab$ may not be well-defined.

Comment: lol. that is great. thank you @Divide1918